# mongoose exclude field in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have something like:

```
Schema Subdocument
name: String
data: Mixed

Schema Stuff
documents: [Subdocument]
```

Now, in my API there are two endpoints, one for the `Subdocument` and another for `Stuff`. When I want to get a `Subdocument` I need to contain the `data` field, but when I want to get `Stuff`, I want to show the name of those subdocuments, but I don't want to show the data field because is quite large and it won't be used.

So, to keep things clear, data is not private. It's just that I don't want it to be shown when I get it from `Stuff`

I tried by doing:

```
Stuff.findById(id)
     .populate("documents")
     .populate("-documents.data")
```

but that doesn't work... I'm getting the `Stuff`with the `Subdocument`containing the `name` and `data`. I feel like i'm missing to tell mongoose when I call `populate("-documents.data")` that `documents` is an array and I want to exclude the `data` field for each element in this array.

edit: Sorry the Schema I provided was not for my case. In my case it was not embedded, but a reference, like so:

```
Schema Subdocument
name: String
data: Mixed

Schema Stuff
documents: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Subdocument'
}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming subDocument is not embedded and using as "ref" as you say populate is working but data part is not included:

```
Stuff.findById(id).populate( { "path" : "documents", "select" : "-data" })
```

Comment: Great, that works. I tried this before but I was editing findById() and calling the getAll() method from the API to test it, so I couldn't see any result. Thank you so much!

Comment: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#query-conditions

Answer (score 2):

Your documents have an "embedded" schema, so populate is not used here, it is used only for "referenced" schemas where the other objects are in another collection.

Fortunately with "embedded" there is an easy way using  projection:

```js
Stuff.findById(id,{ "documents.name": 1 },function(err,results) {

})
```

With results like

```js
{ "documents": [{ "name": "this" },{ "name": "that" }] }
```

Or with `.aggregate()` and the [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator:

```js
Stuff.aggregate(
    [
        { "$match": { "_id": ObjectID(id) } },
        { "$project": {
            "documents": { 
                "$map": {
                   "$input": "$documents",
                   "as": "el",
                   "in": "$$el.name"
                }
            }
        }}
    ],function(err,results) {

    }
)
```

That will just tranform into an array of "only" the name "values", which is different to the last form.

```js
{ "documents": ["this", "that"] }
```

Note, if using `.aggregate()` you need to properly cast the `ObjectId` as the autocasting from mongoose schema types does not work in aggregation pipeline stages.

Comment: I'm so sorry about my question... as Hiren says, it's not embedded, I just copied wrongly. It's a reference.... This is one of those situations I don't know who to give the answer....

Comment: @olivarra1 Let us put this down to a learning experience of how to present your question. The syntax you originally used "implies" an embedded schema since that is how you define one in code. Next time you ask a question, copy in the relevant parts of your code. Such as your actual schema definition. Also noting you did not even add that information until after accepting the other answer here.